# WPF split PathFigureCollection into path per segment

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a external function that creates a `System.Windows.Media.PathFigureCollection`.
If I want to see it in my `XAML`. I can do something like this:

```
PathFigureCollection myCollection = ExternalMethod();
Path myPath = new Path();
myPath.Data = new PathGeometry(myCollection);
```

But I need every single segment in `myCollection` as `Path` and not all together in one.
How can I split my `PathFigureCollection` into single `Path`s with `X` and `Y` coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Create a PathGeometry for each Figure in the PathFigureCollection:

```
foreach (var figure in myCollection)
{
    var geometry = new PathGeometry();
    geometry.Figures.Add(figure);

    Path path = new Path
    {
        Data = geometry,
        // other properties
    };

    // add Path to Canvas
}
```